# Julia Keyboard Interrupt

Tags: keyboard, julia

How would I interrupt a Julia command with the keyboard? I'm running it in the Terminal interface. For example, in Python, IDLE permits me to throw an error in a `while True` loop by pressing `ctrl-C`. I would like to be able to do the same thing in Julia.
Thanks!

Comment: ctrl-C should work in Julia also, so if it doesn't it is a bug. If you are using the most recent nightly build, you should submit a bug report including your versioninfo(), and steps to reproduce, on https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia

Comment: using v0.2.0-rc1 I find that Ctrl-C works to break out of a `while true` loop. To quit the REPL, it doesn't work but Ctrl-D does.

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl+c works in the Julia REPl. In Juno you use Ctrl+j Ctrl+k.

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me in either Julia's own REPL, cmd running the Julia REPL, or Powershell running the Julia REPL. If I hold Ctrl and press C four times rapidly, it does interrupt the process (like `while true end`), but then it crashes out of the REPL entirely, trashing my workspace.

Comment: And in [Pluto.jl](https://github.com/fonsp/Pluto.jl) what should I type ?